# Relay getting traffic showing as unreachable?

Tags: relays

UPDATE: See my answer below for instructions, I added a Dynamic DNS and added that as the "Address" in torrc. Once I did that I got the "Self-testing indicates your ORPort is reachable. Excellent." message.

I recently started a relay and it appears to be getting traffic OK but the log shows:
"Your server (3.11.33.113:443) has not managed to confirm that its ORPort is reachable."
"Your server (3.11.33.113:9030) has not managed to confirm that its DirPort is reachable."

I have ORPort advertised on 443 and binding to 9001.

If I check netstat:

```
watch -d -n0 "netstat -atnp | grep 9001"
```

I can see established connections to other Tor relays (I checked the IPs in Atlas).

I tested the port forwarding via YouGetSignal and it says the ports are open. I also tested the ports for outbound traffic via portquiz and they worked fine.
**Is the not managed to confirm error something I need to actively try to fix? *If so, how?***

Router: Asus RT-N66U w/DD-WRT

Enabled port forwarding through: NAT / QoS => Port Forwarding

Here is a copy of the Port Forwarding table on my router:

```
Application | Protocol | Source Net | Port from | IP Address | Port to | Enable
Tor-Dir     | TCP      | [blank]    | 63118     | 3.11.33.113 | 63118  | Checked
Tor-OR      | TCP      | [blank]    | 443       | 3.11.33.113 | 9001   | Checked
```

Relay is being assigned the above IP via static lease tied to it's MAC Address. I have checked the IP address via ifconfig eth0 to confirm it has 3.11.33.113 as it's address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since my IP is dynamic (and Tor couldn't figure out my IP) I had to create a Dynamic DNS and used that in the Address field in torrc.

Once I did that both DirPort and ORPort were able to establish connections.

I used a Dynamic DNS from [dnsexit](https://www.dnsexit.com/Direct.sv?cmd=freeSub), the additional options were taken from [this post](https://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=919601&sid=2834fa5f4dc9e59b97d568ca4f5f69d7#919601) on the DD-WRT forums. They are:

```
--verbose 5 --update_period_sec 43200 --ip_server_name checkip.ns.zerigo.com /
```

Here's an example settings screenshot for DD-WRT:
[image: DynamicDNS screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to fix it, otherwise the Tor network will never learn about your relay. Are you sure the port forwarding from port 443 to port 9001 actually works? Maybe the forward is going to the wrong place.

For testing, just bind and advertise a high port and don't do any port forwarding.

Comment: I disabled port forwarding in my router and changed the port from 443 to random ones (ORPort 50820 NoListen and ORPort 0.0.0.0:42000 NoAdvertise) and get the same errors (not managed to confirm that its ORPort/DirPort is reachable.)

Comment: If you're behind a NAT, you need to do portforwarding for that port, of course. How to correctly configure your home router is kind of out of scope for this here, and depends on your model and/or maybe even your ISP. Also, why did you use NoListen and NoAdvertise? What do you hope to gain from these options? They're most likely wrong.

Comment: The NoListen/NoAdvertise options were there by default, I just changed the port.

After doing some additional testing, though, I wonder if my ISP is doing something funky. I changed the ORPort back to 443 without binding and DMZ'd the relay but it still logs as unreachable. I double-checked with ifconfig to make sure the relay has the correct IP.

I'll try to contact my ISP this week and what they say.

Answer (score 1):

This probably means there's an issue with your port forwarding configuration.  More information here would be helpful.

- What Router do you have?
- Can you explicitly say what you edited to configure port forwarding? What changes you made?
- Are you sure you're forwarding the ports on the correct internal IP (the IP of whatever computer is running your relay?).

Zach

Comment: I've updated the OP with this info.

Comment: Cool - glad you were able to figure it out.  If you're able to be more explicit about what you did to create the Dynamic DNS that would be helpful for future people.  Thanks!